# Serializing Foundation and non-foundation types to JSON in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsjsonserialization, jsonencoder

I'm trying to serialize two different types of object to `JSON`, but I've only been able to do so  using `JSONEncoder` for one, and `JSONSerialization` for the other.

One is a simple `Int`, which I serialize as follows:

```
let ticket: [String:Any] = ["ticket": -1]
let ticketJson = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ticket)
let ticketJsonString = String(data: ticketJson, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

The other object type is a class I created, which I serialize as follows:

```
let encodedNotification = try! JSONEncoder().encode(notification)
let encodedNotificationJsonString = String(data: encodedNotification, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Ideally, I would serialize both at once, using the following dictionary:

```
let parameters: [String:Any] = ["ticket": -1, "notification": notification]
```

Is this possible? If so, how? I have not been able to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the values in a struct rather than a `[String: Any]`.

```
struct Parameters: Encodable {
    let ticket: Int
    let notification: Notification
}

let parameters = Parameters(ticket: -1, notification: notification)

let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
```

As a rule, avoid `Any` in Swift. It is a very difficult type to use correctly and does not play particularly nicely with the type system. Except in fairly advanced code, it mostly shows up due to ObjC-bridging (such as in JSONSerialization, which is a bridge to the ObjC NSJSONSerialization).

Comment: Thanks. How did I not think of this? :(
Anyway, is there any issue if I create the struct inside the function I'm using to create the request?

Comment: That's totally fine and good practice. You can create a local struct type that is private to a single function. Like a local variable, it can even have the same name as local structs you use in other functions without causing collisions.